# RegEx (php) - unite lines in multiline replacement

Tags: php, regex

I need change background of all text that have two spaces from the start of the line.

```
  text
```

shold be converted to "`<div class='special'>text</div>`"

That is easy:

```
$text = preg_replace("|^  (.+)|um", "<div class='special'>$1</div>", $text);
```

But

```
  line1
  line2
```

Is converted to

```
<div class='special'>line1</div>
<div class='special'>line2</div>
```

Though

```
<div class='special'>line1
line2</div>
```

is needed.

How that can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
((?:^  [^\r\n]*(?:\R(?=  ))?)+)
```

with `<div class='special'>$1</div>`.

But this will convert

```
  line1
  line2
```

to this:

```
<div class='special'>  line1
  line2</div>
```

If you want to remove the spaces, you should match the text, remove the spaces and then replace.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the "s" (DOTALL) pattern modifier so you can capture multiple lines.  Then stop the greed by matching "newline followed by something other than two spaces"

```
<?PHP
$text = "
  Line One
  Line Two
  Line Three
something";

$text = preg_replace("|^  (.+)^[^(  )]|ums", "<div class='special'>$1</div>\n", $text);


echo $text;
```

Outputs:

```
<div class='special'>Line One
  Line Two
  Line Three
</div>
```

Comment: Your regex fails at many cases. (.+) will make it match anything after two spaces as long as it ends with a "newline followed by something other than two spaces".

Comment: While I was shooting from the hip, I think that's exactly what Qiao is asking for.  How are you reading the requirement?

Comment: "change background of all text that have two spaces from the start of the line". Well, your solution changes lines that don't start with two spaces in this case: "  asdf\n1234\n5678".